# Modal in Layout ASP.NET Razor Pages

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I try to make a little project.

It is created in C# ASP.NET with Razor Pages and I want to have a modal for sign up but I don't know how to implement it.

I found a lot of things doing by MVC, and I don't know if this is a solution.

I tried doing it by MVC, but the layout doesn't have a controller and I don't know how to return the partial view.

Here is the code from the layout, just a little part.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- .... -->
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <header class="headerStyle">
                        <a class="nav-link li-modal" id="myModal" href="/" onclick="CreateUser(event)">
                            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="22" height="22" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-person-plus-fill" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                <path d="M1 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 6-4 6 3 6 4-1 1-1 1H1zm5-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6z" />
                                <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M13.5 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5V7h1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H14v1.5a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0V8h-1.5a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1H13V5.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5z" />
                            </svg>
                            Sign Up
                        </a>               
    </header>
    <div class="bodymain">
        
        <div id="modalplace">

        </div>

        <main role="main">
            @RenderBody()
        </main>
        <div class="push"></div>
    </div>
    <footer class="footer">
        <div class="myfooter">
            test test teste testes tes
        </div>
    </footer>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

    @await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

This is the javascript code.

```
function CreateUser(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = appSettings + "/AddEditUserModal";
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#modalplace").html(data);
            $("#addUser").modal('show');
        }
    })
}
```

The modal's HTML is here.

```
@model Models.AddEditUserModalM

    <div class="model fade" id="addUser" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="addUserLabel">Add user account</h4>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span> X </span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="Create">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputFirstName" class="form-label">First Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <label for="inputLastName" class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName">
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-footer">

                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-save="modal">
                        Save
                    </button>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And I have another class that is a controller for this Modal. It contains this method.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            AddEditUserModalM usr = new();

            return PartialView("AddEditUserModal", usr);
        }
```

I think I need a controller for Layout, or I don't know how to return the modal's code in div id="modalplace".

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,you need to make sure the partial view `AddEditUserModal` is put in the right place,For example,`Shared/AddEditUserModal.cshtml`.
Then you need to change

```
<div class="model fade" id="addUser" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

to

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addUser" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
```

in your partial view.So that the code will work.

And in my demo,I'm using the `bootstrap.bundle.min.js` locally which version is 4.3.1.

```
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: What to change there? It's same

Comment: Check your code `<div class="model fade" id="addUser" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">`the class id `model` rather than `modal`.

Comment: Now I have a javascript error "Uncaught ReferenceError: appSettings is not defined", what is this. I tried to change "appSetting" into "appSettings" but no result.

Comment: Can you update your code to share where you use `appSettings`  in js?

Comment: It's in the description, after this "This is the javascript code."

Comment: It is because you never define appSettings,you need to define it before you use it.

Comment: That javascript was copied from the internet, I don't know how to load the modal's code from an external file in the layout's body.

Comment: You need to do like `var appSettings ="xx"`(define it with the value you want) before you use it.

Comment: but I don't know what to define for it